# androidhive login script modification

Tags: php, android, mysql, authentication

I have finished the following Tutorial:
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

All is fine. But when I try to log in I can use any password and I get access.

How can I modify the function with the result that I need the right password for the login.

```
public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password) {

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = ?");

    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        $stmt->close();
        return $user;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

I tried following code, but with this code I don't get access anymore.

```
public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?";
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
    $result = $this ->conn->query($sql);



    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        $hashed_password = $this->checkhashSSHA($user["salt"],$password);

    if($hashed_password == $user["encrypted_password"]){
        $stmt->close();
        return $user;
    }
    else{
        $stmt->close();
        return NULL;
    }
    }
    else {
        $stmt->close();
        return NULL;
    }

    $stmt->close();
}
```

There are this hash functions. Maybe there are problems with it?!

```
/**
 * Encrypting password
 * @param password
 * returns salt and encrypted password
 */
public function hashSSHA($password) {

    $salt = sha1(rand());
    $salt = substr($salt, 0, 10);
    $encrypted = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);
    $hash = array("salt" => $salt, "encrypted" => $encrypted);
    return $hash;
}

/**
 * Decrypting password
 * @param salt, password
 * returns hash string
 */
public function checkhashSSHA($salt, $password) {

    $hash = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);

    return $hash;
}
```